# Error in sudo apt update

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

I when write `sudo apt update` give me this error

```
Hit:1 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                              
Hit:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                         
Get:4 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]                             
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                       
Get:6 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [107 kB]              
Fetched 336 kB in 3s (124 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Error in `apt list --upgradable` what is the solve

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error here.  `apt update` does NOT actually upgrade your packages, it only refreshes the info on available packages.

The next step you need to run is `sudo apt upgrade` or `sudo apt dist-upgrade` in order to *install* the packages that need to be installed to complete the update.